# Oracle : How can conditionally Update the first ID of a column based on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: TableA and TableB.

Table A :

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0021 | Cell 2 |
| 0033 | Cell 4 |
| 0021 | Cell 1 |
| 0036 | Cell 6 |

Table B

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0021 | Cell 8 |
| 0033 | Unknown |

I want to update the Value of ID in Table A based on the results of Table B :
If TableB.Value like '%Cell%', Update the first record with ID (0021 in the exemple) of Table A

After searching, I have written this (But it does not take the condition correctly, and update all rows with the ID found) :

```
UPDATE TableA
SET TableA.Value = (SELECT TableB.Value
                    FROM TableB
                    Where Value like '%Cell%'
                    AND TableA.ID = TableB.ID) ;
```

Comment: MySQL & SQL Server are **completely** different products to Oracle - and work completely differently - please correct your tags.

Comment: Done, only SQL and ORACLE tags are on now

Comment: Why do you want to update only one row ("the first", as you said) in table A whose ID = 0021? How do you know that it is the first? Just by looking at table's contents? That's wrong - in a relational table, rows don't have any specific order and you can't tell which is the first or which is the last. There must be some identifier which says so, but - you didn't tell it and we don't know it.

Comment: The data have a third column with a Date that is used to order them

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a MERGE statement, without an INSERT, would help in this situation.  Example:

**Tables & data**

```
-- table A with date column, as specified in your comment 
create table tablea (date_, id, value) 
as
select sysdate,     '0021', 'Cell 2' from dual union all
select sysdate - 1, '0033', 'Cell 4' from dual union all
select sysdate - 2, '0021', 'Cell 1' from dual union all
select sysdate - 3, '0036', 'Cell 6' from dual;

create table tableb (id, value)
as
select '0021', 'Cell 8'  from dual union all
select '0033', 'unknown' from dual;
```

**Tables before merging**

```
select * from tablea order by date_ ;

DATE_       ID      VALUE
31-OCT-22   0036    Cell 6
01-NOV-22   0021    Cell 1
02-NOV-22   0033    Cell 4
03-NOV-22   0021    Cell 2

select * from tableb ;

ID      VALUE
0021    Cell 8
0033    unknown
```

**Merge**

```
merge into tablea T using (
  select id, value from tableb
) T2 on ( 
       T.id = T2.id 
   and T2.value like '%Cell%' 
   and T.date_ = ( select min( date_ ) from tablea where id = T.id )
)
when matched then 
  update
  set T.value = T2.value 
;
```

Table A after MERGE

```
select * from tablea order by date_ ;

DATE_       ID      VALUE
31-OCT-22   0036    Cell 6
01-NOV-22   0021    Cell 8
02-NOV-22   0033    Cell 4
03-NOV-22   0021    Cell 2
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9HXaTmeu)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below:

```sql
Update A_TABLE a
    Set a.ID = (Select Max(ID) From B_TABLE Where VALUE LIKE('%Cell%'))
Where
    a.ID = (
              SELECT ID FROM 
                (Select * From (Select ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) "RN" From A_TABLE) 
              WHERE RN = 1)
           ) And
    a.VALUE = (
                SELECT VALUE FROM 
                    (Select * From (Select ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) "RN" From A_TABLE) 
                WHERE RN = 1)
              )
```

But if you want to see something happening in A_TABLE you should change the ID in B_TABLE with the VALUE LIKE('%Cell%'). Because with your sample data you will update the ID in A_TABLE (which is '0021') with the same ID from B_TABLE (also '0021').
A problem could be if you have two identical rows (same ID and same VALUE as in the first row) in A_TABLE - in that case both IDs will be updated.
Also, the Max(ID) is there for possibility that you have more than 1 row in B_TABLE with VALUE LIKE('%Cell%') which will cause an error. Additionaly, if there is a possibility that there are no rows in B_TABLE with appropriate VALUE column then there should be Nvl function to handle that:

```sql
...
Set a.ID = Nvl((Select Max(ID) From B_TABLE Where VALUE LIKE('%Cell%')), a.ID)
...
```

... this will update the ID in A_TABLE with itself - so nothing happens.
Regards...